# flex 4 php communication

Tags: php, flash, apache-flex, class, actionscript

i have new discovered Flex 4 and i think, that it is great, but i can't do simple things in it. for example, i want communication between flex/actionscript and php class, so i have created php class:

```
<?php
class main{
    public static function test_function(){
        return 'hello';
    }
}
?>
```

and i can't find out how to retrive 'hello' from that class in Actionscript

```
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        function button1_click():void{
            Alert.show(test_function()); // this is mistake
        }
    ]]>
```

so i know that this is mistake, but i don't know how to do correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [**example of login dialog with Flex and PHP**](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2966311/Flex-using-PHP-) should help you.

Comment: public var gateway : RemotingConnection; <-- here is an error; Multiple markers at this line: -1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: RemotingConnection. -gateway

Comment: At end of page 5 / beginning of page 6, the tutorial explains that you have to create a `RemotingConnection.as` file and tells you what to write into it. Please read.

Answer (score 0):

Erm, you do know that PHP is a server side language right?  You're missing the whole point of the client-server side communication protocol.

First, make sure you have a web server up being able to serve your php script.  Second, you need to be able to go to your script and using a certain method (like GET/POST variables, REST, SOAP, etc), be able to call your function.  From there, Flex should be able to ping that script through the web server.

But again, you're lacking a lot of knowledge around [how web applications work](http://www.digitalvertebrae.com/webdev/index/title/Web%20Application%20Development%3a%20How%20a%20Web%20Application%20Works/section/weekseven/id/53/) and should read up on it.

Comment: flex is great posibility for client / server side communication. it can call php function from actionscript, but i just don't know how!

Comment: public var gateway : RemotingConnection; <-- here is an error; 
Multiple markers at this line:
-1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: RemotingConnection.
-gateway